# Grafana: How to show only one field in the graph?

Tags: grafana

I have a Piechart and a bar chart and I'm facing the same issue in both charts. For example, in the bar chart, I have this MySQL query

```
SELECT
  time AS "time",
  videoid AS metric,
  sum(mbytes) AS "mbytes",
  video_url AS url,
  video_title as title
FROM topvideos
WHERE
  $__unixEpochFilter(time)
GROUP BY videoid,2
ORDER BY time
LIMIT 10
```

I need all of these fields in different places, but the chart itself, I want it only to show the title, so the user needs to see only the title when looking at the chart.

But I need to have the videoid and URL in order to create a direct link when the user clicks on a bar, so that he's redirected to the video URL.

I tried transformation -> filter by name -> title. But this seems to be changing the data of the chart, some bar becomes bigger than the other.

How to correctly do what I'm looking for? I want the end user to be able to see one field only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `Standard options > Display name` and then set that field to `${__field.labels.title}`

[image]